# AngularJS: how to modify an array in the service from multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to have an array in the service, which can be modified from different controllers. 
The purpose of this is the have an array accessible through every controller.
I want to be able to push items to this array from controllers, as well to delete them.

Service:

```
.service('EmailOps', function () {

        var templates = [];

        return {

        pushToEmailBody: function (newObj) {

            templates.push(newObj);
            console.log(templates);

            }

        };
    });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, EmailOps) {

    $scope.include = EmailOps.pushToEmailBody;

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

<a href="#" ng-click="include('one')">1</a>

<a href="#" ng-click="include('two')">2</a>

<a href="#" ng-click="include('three')">3</a>

</div>
```

To summarize, I would like to be able to add multiple new elements to the array in the service by clicking on these links. Currently when it adds one of them, it replaces the one added before, so that I have an array with one element only. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here : http://jsbin.com/gesirira/1/edit

**service**:

```
   app.service('EmailOps', function () {

        var templates = [];


       function pushToEmailBody (newObj) {

                templates.push(newObj);
                console.log(templates);

                }

      return {

        templates:templates,
        pushToEmailBody : pushToEmailBody 

      };


     });
```

**controller**:

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope,EmailOps){

 $scope.include = function(obj)
 {
   EmailOps.pushToEmailBody(obj);
 };

  $scope.temp = EmailOps.templates;

});
```

**html:**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

  <a href="#" ng-click="include('one')">1</a>

 <a href="#" ng-click="include('two')">2</a>

 <a href="#" ng-click="include('three')">3</a>
    <br/>
    templates: {{temp |json}}
</div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your service like this

```
.service('EmailOps', function () {

    this.templates = [];

    this.pushToEmailBody = function (newObj) {

        templates.push(newObj);
        console.log(templates);

     }
});
```

and then in the controller :

```
$scope.include = function(obj)
 {
   EmailOps.pushToEmailBody(obj);
 };
```